# Make Scrollable Vertical and Horizontal at Tbody

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have problem to make scrollable `tbody` in table. I used bootstrap. I am already make `name` and `category` column sticky also make another column `overflow-x: scroll`.

The problem is how to make `thead` and `tfoot` sticky and only `tbody` in scroll. I am already create jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/awpt6cL0/1/.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution which again is not a CSS only solution it also uses a few lines of jQuery.

Here's a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jazibbashir/292opxen/) for demonstration purposes.

**HTML Code:**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
            <th>Column 3</th>
            <th>Column 4</th>
            <th>Column 5</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 1</td>
            <td>Row 1</td>
            <td>Row 1</td>
            <td>Row 1</td>
            <td>Row 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2</td>
            <td>Row 2</td>
            <td>Row 2</td>
            <td>Row 2</td>
            <td>Row 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 3</td>
            <td>Row 3</td>
            <td>Row 3</td>
            <td>Row 3</td>
            <td>Row 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 4</td>
            <td>Row 4</td>
            <td>Row 4</td>
            <td>Row 4</td>
            <td>Row 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 5</td>
            <td>Row 5</td>
            <td>Row 5</td>
            <td>Row 5</td>
            <td>Row 5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 6</td>
            <td>Row 6</td>
            <td>Row 6</td>
            <td>Row 6</td>
            <td>Row 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 7</td>
            <td>Row 7</td>
            <td>Row 7</td>
            <td>Row 7</td>
            <td>Row 7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 8</td>
            <td>Row 8</td>
            <td>Row 8</td>
            <td>Row 8</td>
            <td>Row 8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 9</td>
            <td>Row 9</td>
            <td>Row 9</td>
            <td>Row 9</td>
            <td>Row 9</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 10</td>
            <td>Row 10</td>
            <td>Row 10</td>
            <td>Row 10</td>
            <td>Row 10</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td>
          FOOTER
        </td>
        <td>
          FOOTER
        </td>
        <td>
          FOOTER
        </td>
        <td>
          FOOTER
        </td>
        <td>
          FOOTER
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

**CSS Code**

```
html {
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 10pt;
    line-height: 25px;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 400px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    display: block;
}
thead {
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
}
thead, tbody {
    display: block;
}
tbody {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 140px;
}
td, th {
    min-width: 100px;
    height: 25px;
    border: dashed 1px lightblue;
}
```

**Jquery Code:**

```
$('table').on('scroll', function () {
    $("table > *").width($("table").width() + $("table").scrollLeft());
});
```

Hope This Helps!

Comment: @jazid thank you but you have idea to make column 1 and 2 fixed?

Comment: @edwinlab use your css solution to fix make column fixed.
.static {
        position:absolute; 
        width:110px;
        top:auto;
      }
      .name {
        left:0;
      }
      .category {
        left:110px;
      }

Tell me if you need more help!
Thanks

Comment: @jazid can you update the jsfiddle i have no idea. Thanks so much